# How to use CAMetalLayer with an NSView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, calayer, metal, metalkit

How to use `CAMetalLayer` ? I try to look some example however some did `NSView.layer.addSubLayer(MetalLayer)` some other do `NSView.layer = MetalLayer`, some other set `NSView.SetWantsLayer = true` before doing `NSView.layer = MetalLayer` (but doing `NSView.SetWantsLayer = true` seam to already assign a layer to the view), etc so I don't know with to choose. Also when i do `NSView.layer = MetalLayer` then my drawrect metal is not call anymore

Comment: `NSView` is the macOS implementation of iOS's `UIView`.  Are you really talking about `UIView`?  If so, edit your question to change `NSView` to `UIView`.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Oh sorry I was talking about NSView, but I set iOS in tag by mistake :(

Answer (score 2):

In AppKit, you make the view layer backed by setting the view’s wantsLayer property. The app explicitly creates a CAMetalLayer object and assigns it to the view’s layer property.

```
self.wantsLayer = YES;
self.layer = [CAMetalLayer layer];
```